# Line up sections of text in different columns

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a web app (C# backend) project that's similar to a diff tool.  In one view, I have two versions of the same text in left and right columns.  They will have all of the same section headers, but not necessarily the same text in the paragraphs.

I have this section in a div, and then each column in its own div.  A friend suggested that I might be able to use some sort of offset-from-the-top CSS property, but I haven't figured out a way to make that workable.  I can't just add a calculated number of new lines (or hardcoded margin adjustments) because each set of data will have different offsets, as well as each screen size.

This is a jsfiddle with a simplified example of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=79sTr7vnDR

Comment: IE 10 and up solution http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @vico : can you explain how a flexbox solution would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in your comment you can't split the data up horizontally. Can you add classes to each side, splitting them vertically? For example, could you wrap the `<h1>`s and their corresponding `<p>` elements in a `<div class="subsection1">` on each side? (I attached a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cw93S/) with an example)

Because if you can, you could use some jquery to calculate the lowest positions of the same classes on each side and set the vertical offset to be equal to the lowest one, and continue. I'd be happy to help you with an example, but I just want to make sure it's viable before I do :P Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, I believe I could do that. I haven't done anything with jquery before: how would that work?

Comment: So I updated the fiddle with jQuery (here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cw93S/1/). Make sure that when you implement this, you add the subsection class names counting upwards. If you uncomment the alerts, it should help to explain what I'm doing in the jQuery! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I put together.

```
<div class="side-by-side-wrapper">
    <div class="content-block">
        <div class="side1">HEre is your header</div>
        <div class="side2">Here is your header from the other side.<p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-block">
        <div class="side1">HEre is content from block 1<p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p></div>
        <div class="side2">Here is content from block 2 <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
    </div>

        <div class="content-block">
        <div class="side1">HEre is footer from block 1<p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p></div>
        <div class="side2">Here is footer from block 2 <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.side-by-side-wrapper
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.side-by-side-wrapper .content-block
{
    clear: both;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.content-block .side1, .content-block .side2
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

If you wrap each section (in my example, `content-block`) in a wrapper, you can use floating and clearing to make them have the same height.  I used some generic styles to prove the point, but the core of this functionality is floating with clearing around each pair (left and right side) of content sections.

Comment: hmm... I understand how this works, but I can't split it up this way.  Based on how the backend code works, I'm going to get each side of text separately, not alternating by section.

Comment: So you don't know where the breaks of your content sections are?  You get all the content as one big block?  So tell me how do you intuitively know where one section ends and the next starts?  How do you know how many sections you have?  If there's a technique you use (e.g. by id) then you can use a server-side HTML parser to break it out the way you need.  For example, see the Html Agility Pack: http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack